# react native getting 'id' of on press target

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am building an auction site where each item is accessed by clicking a button on the home screen which has an id the routed to item screen then a fetch is made to get item data.

How do I get the value assigned to the id property? In production this will be a mongodb id. I am using react native navigation.

```
<TouchableOpacity
  id="5"
  style={[styles.buttonContainer, styles.loginButton]}
  onPress={() => {
    navigate("Item", {
      itemId: "" // what I am trying to find will be 5
    });
  }}
>
  <Icon size={32} />
  <Text style={styles.loginText}>Login using google</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Maybe you can put the `id` in a variable and reuse that in both locations? `id={id} ... navigate("Item", { itemId: id })`?

Comment: no there may 100 plus of these items each with an id

Comment: Sure, but I guess you create these components for each item inside e.g. a `map` method. Then you could put the `id` in a variable for each iteration in this loop.

Comment: right but when the user clicks to view the item i  need that pressed items id to load on the item page

Comment: [I'm thinking something like this](https://babeljs.io/en/repl#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&spec=false&loose=false&code_lz=N4FwFglgzgdFIEMQFMYRQW1hhAHAFOshgAQC8AfCcAFAkkDGA9gHbzUkQAmJAvuZ0wBuGnRIAnZCACu4liXxj6AHgAqTaQzAIARgBtkAeVwIG6AJ5L6nLmWDdeV-qwAKkqFDv4AlOSq1rQJIWBAA3CABzJGR8ACIASUxYgBpqJyCiDHiuAC4bdPpebxEgvkdAgHoKMWKaIt4gA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=false&fileSize=false&timeTravel=false&sourceType=module&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-0%2Cstage-1%2Cstage-2%2Cstage-3&prettier=false&targets=&version=7.3.4)

Comment: Use Redux for state management and store the ID onPress. It will then be accessible throughout your app.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using react native navigation (the wix one), you need to push the screen with a passProps:

```
this.props.navigator.push({
  screen: 'example.ScreenThree', // unique ID registered with Navigation.registerScreen
  passProps: {
    id: actionId
}, // Object that will be passed as props to the pushed screen (optional)
});
```

and then in the Item screen you can retrieve it like this:

```
const { params } = this.props.navigator;
```

And params should have the data you sent in the passProps.

Comment: the question i am asking is how to pro-grammatically  get the value of id from id='5'

Comment: Wait, are you asking how to receive the ID property from MongoDB when you make the query? If so, that is a completely different question. Please post more code so we understand what you are doing and whay you are trying to do.